# How to add line wrap back to a textarea with Bulma button styling

Tags: html, css, bulma

Currently creating a form with Bulma and the entire site is stock dark mode, so to match the theme, I want the form boxes to match. I found that styling with `<input class="input">` didn't work well as you cant read the placeholder text and you cant fix that issue without the use of Sass. With that being said, I found that giving the `input` elements `class="button"`, before then styling them in the same way as I would a button element, working perfectly! However, I also have a `textarea` element, and when I tried to do the same with it, it no longer had line wrap.

Is there any way that I can add line wrap back to the `textarea` element, ideally without the use of Sass?

This is ruffly the textarea element that i was using:
`<textarea class="button is-outlined has-background-black has-text-light has-text-left" placeholder="Placeholder Text"></textarea>`

Example Images:
[Ex. What's happening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6ftG.png)
[Ex. What I'm Looking For](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UnG8.png)